# Upgrade H2 Version from 1.4.X to 2.1.214 ( SpringBoot Upgrade from 2.5 to 2.7 )

Tags: spring-boot

As part of SpringBoot version upgrade from **2.6 to 2.7**,
I am updating version of H2 database from **1.4.x to 2.1.214**. Facing issues with H2 database initialization. If I revert the version back to 1.4.x then scripts are working.

**I am using below configuration -**

```
  spring.datasource.url = jdbc:h2:~/testdb
  spring.datasource.username = sa
  spring.datasource.password = password
  spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
  spring.sql.init.data-locations=test-data.sql
  spring.sql.init.schema-locations=test-ddl.sql
```

Answer (score 0):

Updating the datasource URL did the trick for me.

**spring.datasource.url = jdbc:h2:mem:testdb,DB_CLOSE_DEALY=-1**

Also this is not final solution.

I will recommend you to install H2 DB Version - 2.1.214 locally and try running all DDL+DML scripts manually which are compatible with H2 Version 1.4.x

You might need to update few queries to make those compatible with latest H2 version.(2.1.214)

I have faced datatype issue with timestamp date format.